# capistrano, unix user, permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sudo

I don't really understand what model of unix accounts/permissions is intended with Capistrano.

Let's say I've got a rails app called Widget and I'll be deploying with passenger.   In general, pre-capistrano, I want the entire ./widget directory to be owned by a user called 'widget'. And then by default default passenger will run the app process as user 'widget' too, because passenger runs as user that owns the file.

And the whole point of this is for that 'widget' account to have fairly limited permissions, right? Since a web app will be running under that account?

So since I want the files to be owned by 'widget', I tell cap

set :user, "widget"

But now when I run "cap deploy:setup", it wants to 'sudo' from that account. No way that 'widget' account gets sudo privileges, the whole point is keeping this account limited privs.

Okay, I can tell cap not to use sudo... but then it won't actually have privs to do what it needs, maybe.

I can find a workaround to this too. But I start thinking, why do I keep having to re-invent the wheel? I mistakenly thought the point of cap recipes was to give me some best practices here. Anyway... what do people actually do here?

Use one unix account for install, but then have cap somehow 'chown' it to something else? Use one unix account, but have something non-cap (puppet?) do enough setup so that account doesn't need to sudo to get things started? What? What am  I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid some of the headache by using Passenger most commonly with Nginx as your webserver.

Then to restart web services the unprivileged Widget user creates a file in his path and Passenger will automatically restart Nginx when it sees that file being present.

This is enabled via the following in your config/deploy.rb:

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

As for other privileged tasks for MySQL/DB administration your database.yml provides the credentials necessary to handle rake migration tasks.

So really the only time you would need something more privileged would be for system wide installation of gems, ruby, or rails updates, but a lot of that depends on how your production environment was setup/installed.

Given Passenger+Nginx and separate credentials for DB you can disable sudo and see if you encounter any errors during your Capistrano deploy process and then pickup from there.

Comment: I understand tmp/restart.txt with passenger (with either apache or nginx).  But that doesn't answer my question, how people generally handle accounts and permissions, what account(s) are setup for cap to login as, what account ends up owning the files, if it's a different account how you make that work, etc.